# help with integration: conditioning on a variable

Tags: calculus, integration

I have a joint probability density that is defined over 3 variables as $f(x, y, z)$.

So, usually if I want to find the marginal probability for a variable, I would do something like:

$$
f(x) = \int\int f(x, y, z) \:dy \:dz
$$

Now, suppose I want to compute the marginal probability of a variable when the value for another variable is given. This is related to conditioning in a probability distribution. So, suppose $x = x_0$ and I want to find out $f(y)$. Can I treat all the expressions in the integral containing $x$ as constants wrt y and replace them with $x_0$. So that:

$$
f(y) = \int f(x_0, y, z) \:dz
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the formula $f_y(y|x=x_0)=\frac{f(x,y)}{f_x(x=x_0)}$.

So you need to find the density function of $f(x,y)$ and $f_x(x)$, which you should be able to calculate it by yourself.

Hope this helps!